# jQuery Mobile's collapsible is slow to execute with iScroll5

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 | jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 | iScroll5 | PhoneGap 3.3.0

I have a series of collapsible divs that are supposed to open on tap.

If I tap a div, collapsible doesn't execute right away. Sometimes it takes 3 seconds, other times it'll take 30 seconds.

UNLESS I tap a div and then immediately scroll the iScroll the container. At whatever time the container is scrolled, the collapsible element fires immediately.

When I check the reaction times on my desktop computer, clicking works perfectly. It's just tapping that seems to have the issue.

When I remove iScroll5, collapsible fires on both click and tap (but obviously I can't scroll the div).

**The Ultimate Question: How can I make collapsible fire immediately on tap?**

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been solved somewhere between upgrading from iScroll5beta to iScroll5 proper and jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.